# Autocomplete filepath or show suggestions when adding file using git in zsh

Tags: git, zsh, autocomplete

Let's say following is the output of my `git status` command.

```
On branch LG-201
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/LG-201'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   src/server/http/index.ts
    modified:   src/server/http/routes.ts

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .vscode/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

When I need to add these unstaged files, I currently have to type `git add` and then manually copy and paste the file paths.

What I'm aiming for is to have an autocompletion feature where, when I type `git add` or its equivalent alias like `ga`, I automatically receive suggestions for the modified files. I would like to choose one of the suggested options using my arrow keys since I'm using Zsh.

I've attempted to use tools like [Facebook PathPicker](https://github.com/facebook/pathpicker/) and `compctl`. I also added the following function to my `.zshrc`:

```
_autocomplete_unstaged_paths() {
  reply=($(git status --porcelain | grep '^.[^?AD] ' | cut -c4-))
}

compctl -K _autocomplete_unstaged_paths
```

However, I haven't been able to achieve the desired autocompletion behavior yet. I'm relatively new to using Zsh, and I'm not very familiar with its built-in plugins and tools. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance on how to make this autocompletion feature work as intended.

Comment: Firstly, you don't need to add each file manually, you can always do e.g. `git add src/*`. Secondly, there surely are ready-made solutions for zsh for such autocompletion. Have you looked for them?

Comment: I prefer not to add all the files simultaneously since each file requires a distinct commit message. I've tried exploring the native options, but I couldn't successfully implement any of them. I believe I'll need step-by-step assistance from someone.

Comment: Maybe I'll have time for full answer later, but I'd recommend looking at e.g. oh-my-zsh which has functionalities like that as extensions. It could be as simple as installing/configuring that and adding the proper extension.